# if else statement before api action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, botframework

Is it possible something like this in web api :

```
 [Route("api/bot1/messages")]
    [BotAuthentication(id = ..., pass = '']
    [Route("api/bot2/messages")]
    [BotAuthentication(id = 2..., pass = 2...]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
```

PS : I'm noob.

Comment: Could you please try to elaborate further on your question?

What are you trying to accomplish, what is your end goal? Have you tried this code yet, and if so, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm trying to "serve" multiple bots using one bot instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the `[BotAuthentication]` attribute, [located here.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d0/d3b/_bot_authentication_8cs_source.html)

```
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Connector
{
     [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
     public class BotAuthentication : ActionFilterAttribute     {

        ...
     }
}
```

In the `[AttributeUsage()]` attribute ([documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)), we see that there is a property inside of the class:

```
AllowMultiple = false
```

From the [documentation for the AllowMultiple property:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether more than one instance
>   of the indicated attribute can be specified for a single program
>   element.
>
> true if more than one instance is allowed to be specified; otherwise, false. The default is false.

This means that more than one `[BotAuthentication]` instance can not be specified for the Messages Controller.

So no, something like that is **not possible.**

(Also, as a note for next time, try to relate your question to the code you have posted. In no way do you say how you are using an "if-else" control statement in your code, and some people might not be able to infer what you mean.)